# Flickery Textures in andEngine

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I'm having problems with my textures in andEngine

```
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    mTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(),
            480, 800);
    fruitTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mTextureAtlas, this, "fruitsprites.png");
    fruitBG = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
            mTextureAtlas, this, "gamebg.png");
    try {
        mTextureAtlas
                .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                        0, 1, 1));

    } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mTextureAtlas.load();
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This causes my whole texture atlas to appear on the screen; on my S4, the texture flickers continuously and the textures are upside down - it looks like the image was chopped up partially in a triangle.
On the emulator, the contents of the entire texture atlas is shown, the screen doesn't flicker, but the textures are upsidedown.

Also `fruitBGSprite.setVisible(true);` just makes the texture completely invisible (but the screen does not flicker)My goal right now is to set just 1 texture as my background.

Comment: load your texture atlas  i.e.mTextureAtlas.load(); this line is missing

Comment: I did load the altas right before `pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();`

Comment: You are using same texture for different regions (i.e. fruitTextureRegion and fruitBG).Check this.Try with different textures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create mTextureAtlas variable of `ITexture` class and fruitTextureRegion,fruitBG variables of `ITextureRegion`